# mysql limit rows per user in login log table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, sql-delete

I have a mysql table with 1 row per user login to our site. I only want to keep the last 10 or so logins for each user. Some users login every day; others only once a month. So I can't just delete rows older than a certain amount of time.

How can I delete rows 11 and higher for a certain user (when sorted by `login_date`)? I have columns for `user_id` and `login_date`. For each `user_id` I only want to keep the most recent 10 rows; the rest should be deleted (which will happen via a cron job run every night; its okay if during the day there are more than 10 login records per user; just trying to prevent the data from becoming too large over time).

Answer (score 2):

Why not hook the process that creates the new login row to also delete the last one if there are 10 or more?

Deleting them as you is a better alternative imo than batch deleting them as they grow.. as your app grows the overhead will get out of hand and generally lead to headscratching.

Comment: Or better, use an [INSERT trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html) to delete the extra rows.

Comment: I like the idea of deleting after inserting if there are more than 10 rows for that user. Is there an easy way in mysql to get a value from the 10th row of results? I'd like to do something like: DELETE * FROM user_logins WHERE user_id=xxx AND login_date < [login_date value of the 10th row WHERE user_id = xxx ORDER BY login_date DESC]

Comment: @mu is too short: Triggers are mad dodgy in mysql, and so I shy away from suggesting them unless I know for a fact that they're working on a database with a working implementation.

Comment: @Mike Scanlin: I'd arrange for exactly 10 records each (using your existing idea, but only once) and then do a `DELETE FROM login_table WHERE id = (SELECT id from login_table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)` after each login. Or somesuch, I'll leave the implementation to you.

Comment: Fair enough, I usually use PostgreSQL and triggers are not dodgy there. But don't you mean `ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10` or something more like that? Or maybe an `IN` and larger `LIMIT` to be a bit more paranoid.

Comment: I use Postgre when it'd my choice as well. `LIMIT 1` and `ORDER BY ASC` ought to return the single lowest ID allowing you to toast one row after adding one row. That's how I'd approach the problem.

Comment: Ah. OFFSET. Didn't know that one. That should do it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your retention policy by nightly running this:

```
    DELETE logins.*
      FROM logins
           -- Find those records with 10+ more recent records
INNER JOIN (   SELECT l.user_id, l.login_date
                 FROM logins l
            LEFT JOIN logins t
                   ON l.user_id = t.user_id AND l.login_date <= t.login_date
             GROUP BY 1, 2
               HAVING COUNT(1) > 10) too_old
        ON logins.user_id = too_old.user_id AND logins.login_date = too_old.login_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this suffice?

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE login_date > DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```